# Error message when use addLayer in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

I use this code to make a join of 2 files of 2 files want to generate json files:

```
function join(){         
    $.when(
        $.getJSON('bairro.json'),
        $.getJSON('convertJson.php')
    ).done(function(responseGeojson, responseData) {
        var data = responseData[0]
        var geojsonLayer = responseGeojson[0]

        console.log('==geojson==');
        console.log(geojsonLayer);

        var lookup = {};
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            if(item.cod) {
                lookup[item.cod] = {
                    id: item.cod,
                    nome: item.nome,
                    local: item.local
                }           
            }
        })
        console.log('==lookup==');
        console.log(lookup);

        geojsonLayer.features.forEach(function(d) {
            if (lookup[d.properties.CODBAIRRO]) {
                d.properties.joined = lookup[d.properties.CODBAIRRO];
            }
        })

        console.log('==the new==');
        console.log(geojsonLayer);

        L.geoJSON(geojsonLayer).addTo(map);

    })
}
```

But this error message appears:

**TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function**

According to the error presented, the problem is in this line of code:

**L.geoJSON(geojsonLayer).addTo(map);**

I do not know what to do to fix this error, for the code to work.

**UPDATE**

The Jsons behaving well and are valid, I checked on a validator.

Part of  the output of console.log(geojsonLayer); is:

```
{type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array(161)}
  features:Array(161)
    [0 … 99]

      0:
       geometry:
         coordinates:(50) 
            [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
        type:"MultiPolygon"
        __proto__:Object
      properties:{OBJECTID: 325, Área: 1705684.49376977, NOME: "Paquetá", REGIAO_ADM: "PAQUETA", AREA_PLANE: "1", …}
      type:"Feature"
      __proto__:Object

      1:{type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
      2:{type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
      3:{type: "Feature", properties: {…}, geometry: {…}}
```

Comment: How do you instantiate your `map`?

Comment: Maybe similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263876/leaflet-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addlayer-of-undefined/263898#263898

Comment: Unfortunately that was not helpful, but I see you have some nested arrays.. I'm still quite sure that your geojson structure is not good for leaflet. Anyway can you make jsfiddle of it or give link to example of your data to make some test?

Comment: The link of example http://rodolfomarriel.com/projeto/avisp/error.php. You can see the data in the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error appears in this case if **your layer is not correctly interpreted as JSON**, in example because of bad file structure or your `geojsonLayer` variable is empty so that `addTo(map)` function cannot process it.

You may add some error handling to your `$.getJSON` functions:

```
$.getJSON("YOUR-FILE.JSON", function() {
  console.log("success");
})
.success(function() { console.log("success"); })
.error(function() { console.log("error"); })
.complete(function() { console.log("complete"); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){
   if(status == 'parseerror'){
    console.log("not valid json");
   } else {
    console.log("some other error?");
   }
});
```

How are your JSONs behaving on this handlers?

Your code combine two files from different sources so probably the output file structure is not correct as JSON or one of your files has wrong structure to be interpreted as JSON/geoJSON. Can you post your output to some JSON validator? Is it valid?

Can you please upload output of your `console.log(geojsonLayer);`?

You may check adding these files separately with this script - do they separetely add properly to your map?

I would also strongly suggest you to process your files on server in PHP script which will output with one single properly structured JSON file.